# RNN L2 Regularization stops learning

Tags: deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, lstm, bidirectional

I use Bidirectional RNN to detect an event of unbalanced occurence. The positive class is 100times less often than the negative class.
While no regularization use I can get 100% accuracy on train set and 30% on validation set.
I turn on l2 regularization and the result is only 30% accuracy on train set too instead of longer learning and 100% accuracy on validation set.

I was thinking that maybe my data is too small so just for experiment I merged train set with test set which I did not use before. Situation was the same as I would use l2 regularization, which I did not now. I get 30% accuracy on train+test and validation.

In use 128hidden units and 80 timesteps in the mentioned experiments
When I increased the number of hidden units to 256 I can again overfit on train+test set to get 100% accuracy but still only 30% on validation set.

I did try so many options for hyperparameters and almost no result. Maybe the weighted cross entropy is causing the problem, in given experiments the weight on positive class is 5. While trying larger weights the results are often worse around 20% of accuracy.

I tried LSTM and GRU cells, no difference.

The best results I got. I tried 2 hidden layers with 256 hidden units, it took around 3 days of computation and 8GB of GPU memory. I got around 40-50% accuracy before it starts overfitting again while l2 regularization was on but no so strong.

Is there some general guideline what to do in this situation? I was not able to find anything.

Comment: Your question might be better suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Too much hidden units can overfit your model. You can try with smaller number of hidden units. As you mentioned, training with more data might improve the performance. If you don't have enough data, you can generate some artificial data. Researchers add distortions to their training data to increase their data size but in a controlled way. This type of strategy is pretty good for image data but certainly if you are dealing with text data, probably you can use some knowledge base that can improve the performance.

There are many works going on using Knowledge-bases to solve NLP and deep learning related tasks.